# ACL not honored by mv and tar

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, acl

I'm trying to setup an area on my `ext4` filesystem (on Debian Jessie), where all "staff" group members can read and write existing and newly created files.

The filesystem is mounted with acl option:

```
$ more /etc/fstab | grep acl
UUID=f47c5337-a6e1-4554-b8c0-e05c761ec835 / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
```

I've created a few bash script in order to set ACL's on a directoty and test it against various scenarios.

The first one (`createtestdir.sh`) creates a test directory with a few files and dir inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1  ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 /path/to/new/directory"
    exit
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ] && [ ! -f "$1" ] && [ ! -L "$1" ]
then    
    mkdir $1
    mkdir $1/dir
    touch $1/file
    touch $1/dir/file
    echo "Directory $1 created"
else
    echo "$1 already exist"
fi
```

The second one (`setacl.sh`) set permissions and ACL's on the specified directory, maybe problems arise here:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1  ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 /path/to/directory"
    exit
fi

if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    chgrp -R staff $1
    chmod g+rwxs $1
    setfacl -dm group:staff:rwx $1
    /usr/bin/find $1 -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +
    /usr/bin/find $1 -type d -exec setfacl -dm group:staff:rwx {} +
    /usr/bin/find $1 -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} +
    /usr/bin/find $1 -type f -exec setfacl -m group:staff:rw {} +

    echo "Permission changed"
else
    echo "Directory $1 does not exist"
fi
```

Finally the third script (`acltest.sh`) tests ACL's behavior creating file and directories, moving, copying and untarring and archive:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1  ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 /path/to/directory"
    exit
fi

if [ -d "$1" ]
then    
    #testing acl
    mkdir $1/test_dir
    touch $1/test_dir/file
    touch $1/test_file
    # testing mv
    touch $1/file_from_internal
    touch file_from_external
    ls -l file_from_external
    mv file_from_external $1
    # testing tar && cp
    mkdir test_tar
    touch test_tar/file
    tar cjf test.tar.bz2 test_tar
    cp test.tar.bz2 $1
    ls -ld test_tar
    ls -l test.tar.bz2
    rm -rf test_tar
    rm test.tar.bz2
    cd $1
    tar xjf test.tar.bz2
    echo "Test on $1 completed"
else
    echo "$1 already exist"
fi
```

Executing the scripts the scripts in the correct order give you the following output:

```
$ ./createtestdir.sh Acl
Directory Acl created
$ ./setacl.sh Acl/
Permission changed
$ ./acltest.sh Acl/
-rw-r--r-- 1 gabo gabo 0 feb 24 11:58 file_from_external
drwxr-xr-x 2 gabo gabo 4096 feb 24 11:24 test_tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 gabo gabo 146 feb 24 11:24 test.tar.bz2
Test on Acl/ completed
```

I printed out the permissions of the directory and the file that are respectively untarred and copyed inside the Acl test directory, so they can be compared against the respective  files inside the Acl test directory.

As you can see with ls, pemissions and ACL's are not the expected (by me, of course :)

```
$ ls -l Acl/
totale 16
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 gabo staff 4096 feb 24 11:24 dir
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 gabo staff    0 feb 24 11:24 file
-rw-r--r--  1 gabo gabo     0 feb 24 11:24 file_from_external
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 gabo staff    0 feb 24 11:24 file_from_internal
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 gabo staff 4096 feb 24 11:24 test_dir
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 gabo staff    0 feb 24 11:24 test_file
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 gabo staff 4096 feb 24 11:24 test_tar
-rw-r--r--+ 1 gabo staff  146 feb 24 11:24 test.tar.bz2
```

*file_from_internal* is ok. It was created inside the directory and has right permissions and ACL.

*file_from_external* ins't ok. It was moved from the parent directory, it carries the old permissions, and it hasn't the ACL. **It seems that mv command doesn't work with ACL**.

*test.tar.bz2*  is strange. It was copied from the parent directory, it carries the old permissions, and it implements wrong ACL (file is not writeable by staff group):

```
$ getfacl Acl/test.tar.bz2 
# file: Acl/test.tar.bz2
# owner: gabo
# group: staff
user::rw-
group::rwx          #effective:r--
group:staff:rwx         #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

**It seems that cp also does't work with ACL**

*test_tar* directory also doesn't have group write permission, but it inherits ACL default behavior :/

```
$ getfacl Acl/test_tar
# file: Acl/test_tar
# owner: gabo
# group: staff
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx          #effective:r-x
group:staff:rwx         #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:staff:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

If I try to create a file inside test_tar using a different user (member of staff), I get a permission denied error.

What's wrong in my setacl.sh script? Maybe there's some bug/gotcha/behavior that I'm not aware of?

I would like to provide a replicable test suite in order to check it over different environments without typing a lot of shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

This answer only addresses your tar issue.

The tar utility does not retain extended attributes by default. Since SELinux contexts are stored in extended attributes, contexts can be lost when archiving files. Use the tar --selinux option to create archives that retain contexts and to restore files from the archives.

Comment: The problem is when I untar an archive created outside the directory managed with ACL. My expectations would be that the default ACLs were added, just like creating new files.
The same problem arise with cp and mv, so I wonder how ACL can be useful in real word Linux/UNIX usarge...

Comment: I just tried to tar/untar inside the  directory managed with ACL, and it works like a charm. There is no necessity to use the --selinux flag.